# How to lower the Alert volume when starting/ending the dictation?

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

How can we control (lower) the alert sound when starting and ending the dictation in MacOS ?
I tried to control that in the preferences for Alert Volume but it doesn't change anything for the dictation. It seems that the volume of this dictation's alert depends on the Output Volume and not the Alert Volume.
Then it might be very loud so it's quite bad for hears if you use headphones.